# iOS7 navigationBar and TabBar Color is behaving strangely

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

This is what I want. It loads on some of my view controllers.

Hi all,

I am going nuts trying to make the tint color of all of my viewControllers the same. Some appear to be much darker than others. All I want is the light color to be throughout...

[image: This is what I want]

Sometimes I get this ugly dark gray instead... I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. I have checked the .m file and am not setting the tint color or anything... not sure why it wouldnt be consistent on every viewController...

[image: This is what I get]

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Behavior from some of the properties of `UINavigationBar` has changed from `iOS 7`. I already explained in detail in my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19029973/1603072).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in iOS7 navigation bar is by default `translucent=YES` so just change to NO like bellow:-

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
```

and set `Navigaitonbar` color or other property customize like Bellow put this code into Appdelegate class `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and use `appearance` for applying Globally:-

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
     [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:NavigationColor];
} else {
     [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // it set color of bar button item text
     [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor GreenColor]]; // it set color of navigation
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault]; // it set Style of UINavigationBar
     [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor]}]; //It set title color of Navigation Bar
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later

}
```

For tabBar also same this is by default `translucent=YES` change to NO

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks! OK that seems to work if I place it in my viewDidLoad method, but why cant I change the color? I put `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;` in the viewDidLoad method, but I want to change the color to blueColor. I am targeting ios7

Comment: at app delegate class **[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];** or at viewDidLoad **self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];**

Comment: Yes for tab bar same this is by default translucent=YES change to NO

Comment: use appearance so no need to put code in each class in `viewDidLoad` Method take a look my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

A common mistake is setting the `view.backgroundColor` of the View Controller to `clearColor` (both programmatically or via Storyboard). This makes the view actually black instead (since there's nothing beneath the clear view), so everything that is above that view, that has `translucent` property set to `YES`, will show dark grey color (black color + default iOS blur).

To fix this, either set the `translucent` property to `NO` (as Nitin Gohel said), or set the `view.backgroundColor` to white, which's its *actual* default color.

Hope this still helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7.1 there's a bug, which causes `UITabBar` to not listen to Global Tint.

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22323786/1255674

You need to set the tint programmatically. Thanks, Ive ...