# UIToolbar tintColor and barTintColor issues

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uitoolbar, tintcolor

I have code like so:

```
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
colorView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64.0);
colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//colorView.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0);

self.view addSubview:colorView];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Why does the toolbar subview have a different color then my view? The view appears black and the toolbar appears light gray? Is there a blur or something causing this?

Comment: I want to make a 64.0 height toolbar that has the same tintColor as my navigation bar.

Comment: By default, `-barStyle` for `UIToolBar` is `Translucent light` in `iOS7`. You can change it to `Translucent dark`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behavior from some of the properties of `UINavigationBar` has changed from `iOS 7`. I have already explained this thing in my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19029973/1603072).

Take a look at the **Bar style** for `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` :

[image]

---

You can note two points here :

1. You can change the **Bar style** to `translucent dark` instead of `translucent light` (default).
2. You can change the `translucent` property to `NO` from `YES` (default).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it will help you,

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0);
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
toolbar.alpha = 0.0;
```

Change the `tintColor` and `alpha` based on your requirement.