# Glitch with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it just me or in iOS 7 can you not change the text colour of any shared application? For example, if you open up the Mail or iMessage apps does the colour go back to default blue or is there a way to change this? I haven't been able to.

Here are some screen shots.  Notice the blue font colour when choosing the UIActivityViewController shared application:

Here is what it looks like and what I want it to look like when opening mail from MFMailComposerViewController:

[image]

Here's what it looks like when choosing the mail app from the UIActivityViewController:

[image]

The reason I want to change the font colour is because it's hard to read the text font, especially from the shared application iMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029833/ios-7-navigation-bar-text-and-arrow-color)

Answer (score -1):

Change the Background color of the Navigation Bar with

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Use setTintColor to change the color of the barbutton items.