# Change Color of navigationBar of just UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

How do you change the colour of only the UIActivityViewController?

I want to change the colour of just the UINavigationBar of the UIActivityViewController using something like:

```
self.activityViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Glitch with UIActivityViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764552/glitch-with-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change the background color of the `UINavigationBar` before creating and presenting your `UIActivityViewController` with:

```
 [UINavigationBar appearance].backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

HTH

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when inserting it in the button click method that brings up the ActivityView: I inserted it above my [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; and even tried: [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];}];

Comment: I am sorry, I mentioned the wrong property. Pleas try to set the color like that: `[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];`

Comment: That gives the same effect as what I used.  Unfortunately it changes any childViewController tintColor too, which I am avoiding.

Comment: Try to set the tint color of the navigation bar additionally right after the statement above.

Answer (score 0):

Following code maybe help you:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIActivityViewController class], nil]
           setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: I do not think that this code will work, because the `UINavigationBar` is not a subclass of `UIActivityViewController`. `UIActivityViewController` will be embedded within a `UINavigationController`.