# view controller status bar not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, uiwindow

When I set up my app, and run it the status bar doesn't appear. I have a view controller named: "MOVViewController" with .xib file. In the AppDelegate.h I have this:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MOVViewController *viewController_;`

In the .m, I have this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGRect rcScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:rcScreen];
    viewController_ = [[MOVViewController alloc] init];
    [_window addSubview:viewController_.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When I run it, the viewcontroller appears, but there is no status bar. Why?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
                                            animated:NO];
```

You can change StatusBarStyle as you please

Edit: Actually, the method to show/hide the status bar is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Comment: I added this to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, but there is still a black bar where the status bar should be

Comment: So before, you didn't see any status bar. Now, it is black with no text?

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029833/ios-7-navigation-bar-text-and-arrow-color

Comment: i couldn't find anything helpful there

Answer (score 0):

Setting status bar style won't help unless you set `statusBarHidden` property of the application, like below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Also set `UIStatusBarHidden` key in the `Info.plist` file to `NO`.

Comment: I think i found it: you should set your view controller instance `viewController_` as rootViewController for your `_window`. You can do this as `[_window setRootViewController:viewController_]`.