# Different Navigation Bar Back Button Colors for different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose, we have two view controllers - Controller A and Controller B.

Tapping on a particular item on Controller A pushes the Controller B. I set the color of the navigation bar buttons in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in my `AppDelegate.m` using this -

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Works well on every navigation controller I have in my app. What I want is that I have a different color for the buttons on the navigation bar in Controller A and a different color for those in Controller B.

Is this possible?

What I have tried so far...

1. Put this code in the method in Controller A that pushes Controller B -

   ```
   [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   ```

   No go.
2. This went in the `viewWillAppear` method of Controller B -

   ```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   ```

   Nothing

   ```
   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   ```

   Still no change.

   ```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   ```

   *about to slam my machine against the wall

(Writing from my new computer)
What code should I be using to accomplish this and where should I be putting it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see following may be it help you in your problem 
[reference][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19029973/3977940

Comment: It did.. All I did was put this line of code [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; in the viewDidLoad method of Controller B

Answer (score 0):

The line of code should be -

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and it goes in the `viewDidAppear` method of Controller B.

Remember to put it back to your default color in the `viewDidDisappear` method of Controller B so when you navigate from Controller B, you do not get unexpected results.

(maybe the new computer brought me some luck)

Comment: it works if you put it it in the `viewWillAppear' method as well.

Comment: Hmmm... putting the color back to default in viewDidDisappear did not work completely, the right side buttons of the navigation bar are still white

Answer (score 0):

Try to do :

`[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

after update the tintColor of your navbar

Comment: umm.. for changing the color of back button?

Comment: yes sorry, I use this method to update mine when I make changes. 
If this don't work, try : 

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

For example

Comment: It worked without adding this line of code.. just saying

Comment: On a sidenote, I used this to change the style of my status bar for a particular and then changing it back to default so thanks :)