# ios7 navigationbar left UIBarButtonItem issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am updating my big project to ios7 . And When I update left navigation button have problem .
I don't understand What is problem .

ios6: left button image haven't problem  :

[image]

ios7: left button have problem

[image]

Also when I go next viewcontroller back button have same problem in ios7:

[image]

I am using for menu this image: [link](http://appdesignvault.com/downloads/socioville-hamburger-menu.zip) . image is transparent .

How can I solve this problem in ios7 . 
it's big project and ı can't share all code.When I read article , article says it's problem is setTintColor.  right ?

sorry my English.

Thank you .

Comment: [iOS 7 UIBarButton back button arrow color](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18487559/593709)

Comment: you need to create UIButton with image(like this image) and add it to UIBarButtonItem. In ios7 UIButtons and barbuttons showing like this only,it is default.

Comment: @AdilSoomro before I tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem .I added to viewDidLoad method

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
else
{
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.694 green:.164 blue:.105 alpha:1.0f]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed global tint and I use this way to keep my UIBarButtonItem normal.

```
#define kColorGlobalTint [UIColor redColor]
UIColor *defaultColor = [UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil].tintColor;
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:kColorGlobalTint];
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:defaultColor];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:kColorGlobalTint];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the color for your image used in the left top navigational bar button? you can try to change the following.

1. Give the bar button item tint = clear color
2. Give the button item tint under the bar button item as Default and its background as clear color.
3. change Alpha Value of button item to 1.

Comment: I edited question. you can see my image in question. image is transparent

Comment: I want to support also for ios7 early version. it's not worked for me.I solved it . I gonna share my answer